# Is there a way to optimize the process of uninstalling and installing SSMS?

Tags: installation, patching, automation, ssms

in terms of patching sql server 2016 to the latest cumulative patches, I found out that stopping the services helps avoiding lots of inconveniences, specially if there is log shipping and replication involved:

[image]

However,

when [upgrading](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/237071/22336) to the newest SSMS, stopping the services does not seem to make the uninstall of the old version go quicker, it is indeed a very slow process.

[image]

same slow is the installation.

[image]

even having the relevant services stopped for this operation:

[image]

Plus a reboot at the end of the process.

Is there anything that can be done, in order to automate or optimise the process of installing the new SSMS (currently [18.5.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15))?

Comment: Are you installing SSMS where sql server is running ? If so, dont do that. Also, have you tried installing using command line option in silent mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the relatively recent versions of SSMS install side-by-side with each other, so I wouldn't bother removing them honestly. They'll upgrade the current version if it is on the same major release.

The newer versions are being released faster and sometimes can be a bit buggy, so having an older version to fall back on can also be helpful if you encounter a bug.

As far as making it faster, you could try using a package manager like [winget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) (in preview, but by Microsoft) or [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) or any other generic automation software (Ansible, etc.)

There is also the [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#unattended-install) option of SSMS itself, as Kin mentioned. And I will also echo the warning *to not be doing this regularly (or at all) on the actual SQL Server machine*.

Comment: +1 definitely worth having a look, I have SSIS servers with more than one version of SSMS, specially due to the [Class not registered error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/189301/22336)

Comment: or [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/265816/22336)